# SQL Expression wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create a table but I keep getting an SQL Error but I can't figure out why.

This is the error:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '+491634170770 (Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,Type VARCHAR(20),Conte' at line 1 ERROR 1064 (42000):
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax;

This is my statement:

```
CREATE TABLE +491234175789 (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Type VARCHAR(20),
    Content MEDIUMBLOB
);
```

I already tried to find a solution [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-table.html), but my syntax seems to be correctly. I think its because of the name of the table. But using backticks like this   `´+491234175789´` didn't work.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Have a look at the error message.

Comment: @VMai - I must be blind...

Comment: @VMai: It is the job from OP to get the question right. I guess that was the reason Alvaro asked.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Yes, I was terribly misguided by the SQL Server tag and the assertion that backticks (the correct solution) didn't work. But I definitively overlooked the error message.

Comment: Out of curiosity... Are you creating a new table for each customer and calling it after its phone number or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the backtick `:

```
CREATE TABLE `+491234175789` (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Type VARCHAR(20),
    Content MEDIUMBLOB
);
```

However, don't create a table name that requires backticks.  It is just bad form and makes queries harder to read and write -- you are creating problems for the future.  Call it something like:

```
CREATE TABLE t_491234175789 (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Type VARCHAR(20),
    Content MEDIUMBLOB
);
```

Comment: I would suggest to call it something meaningful if possible. Just a range of numbers doesn't help identifying it easily in the future.

Comment: @PatrickHofman . . . I would actually assume that the numbers do mean something to the OP.  Otherwise it is an extra strange table name.

Comment: Well, even if it has meaning a guiding prefix would help.

Comment: the tables name is a phonenumber which is the unique id in my usertable

Comment: @burnaut It's no good idea to create a table for every user. You reference the data of an user in *one table* by a unique id.